# API Management Service - Administrator Group

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have setup an API Management Service for a client.  We have a co-administrator account under their subscription.

We can access the Publisher and Developer portal if we click on the links inside Azure but if we go to the URL directly and enter our email/password associated with our Azure Subscription, we get:

**Email or password is invalid. Please correct the errors and try again.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Management admins have to login through Azure portal. There is no direct login option except for the workaround described in this blog [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/katriend/2015/12/21/using-the-azure-api-management-rest-api-as-workaround-to-rbac-functionality/).

Comment: Is the plan to make this available once the API Management Service has been ported to the new portal?